# Issue on ClickOnce hosting on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Following this [article](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/), I have successfully hosted my `ClickOnce` app to Azure Blob Storage.

But what URL should a user use to install the app. For example, when you publish an app to a website using `VS2019`, it creates a `publish.html` page whose URL a user can use to install the app. But here we don't have that publish.html page. So, what we do in that case?

Comment: Do you see a file with `.application` file extension? We used that when we hosted our ClickOnce application in Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri No, there is no file with `.application` extension. This is a `VSTO` add-in app. Maybe, that's why it does not have that file. What type of app you are using in your scenario?

Comment: In my case it was a WPF Application.

Comment: @GauravMantri That could be the difference here, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

nam. I am very happy to tell you how to generate publish.htm.

After my test, I found the reason why you can't generate piblish.htm. My dev IDE same as you Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019. It may be upgrade and lost some function about publish. You should use vs2017 to publish the application. I try and success.

This link is my demo url, you can check it. [Jason's demo](https://panshubeiclickone.z12.web.core.windows.net/)

And document links of how to set publish settings is below,

[how to set publish setting to generate publish.htm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-specify-a-publish-page-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019)

Add pic about how to configure, right click project->properties->publish->options->deployment

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. My one upvote for that. But I do have to use `VS2019` for other functionalities I'm using in the app that are not there in `VS2017`.

Comment: Okey. Maybe you can copy the publish.htm into same path.^_^ Uou can try it.

Comment: Just now, I try to create same project name and  paste the publish.htm which generate by vs2017 into the path, It works. Nam if it is useful to you,  you can mark me,tks.@nam